# get files via webrequest and webresponse c#

Tags: c#, webrequest, webresponse, file-listing

I'm looking for a way to "scan" my weblocation (using a stream and webrequest/webresponse) to figure out which files are in that particular folder.
I would like to list these files.

Is this possible at all? I've tried several examples online, but none of them gave me the file-list I'm looking for.

Webdav and other local options are no solution as my weblocation cannot be bound to.

If there is another solution (for example using webclient or anything else please let me know. I'll be glad to hear about that too!), I'm not limited to webrequest and webresponse.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sharepointsiteUrl);
   request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
```

Comment: What is a "web location"? What protocol is being used?

Comment: @CodeCaster httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse. Weblocation is a sharepoint location (I'm not using sharepoint server)

Comment: Again, what is a "web location"? How do you address it? How do you write files in it? How do you download files?

Comment: the weblocation is a document library in sharepoint. accessed this way ` byte[] virtualPath = client.DownloadData(link.com/file.doc);

                Response.BinaryWrite(virtualPath);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the web server to give you a list of files if it is not configured for directory browsing.

Comment: I can upload and download files to this location (via webrequest and webclient). So scanning for files should also be possible I think? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @Robuust Those are two separate permissions.  [This link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx) has information on how to check if directory browsing is enabled or disabled.  You don't say in your question but I'm presuming you're rolling with IIS here.  If you're not you can probably just google "(your server software) directory browsing" and methods to check it will come right up.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is basically NOT defined by the HTTP 1.1 standard.

There have been some extensions to HTTP defined which allow for such behaviour - some proprietary (like Frontpage by MS) and some standardized (like WebDAV).

Other potential options are:
IF your web server is configured to return a directory listing via HTML (aka directory browsing, NOT recommended since it poses a potential security problem) or is running some FTP deamon or...

I would strongly recommend WebDAV since that is standardized and is based on HTTP.

BTW: the URL you just added to your question mentions SharePoint - IIRC [Sharepoint has an HTTP-based API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.aspx) (for an example see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470176.aspx)) and can also be configured to provide [WebDAV access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/138422cf-c140-466a-bcd8-cacba51ef886#bb2_WebDAV).